# My tab style selector isn't working

Tags: lightning, custom-object, tab, setup-object, object-manager

After I create a new object and have to select the style for the tab, every time I click a style it doesn't select it and I am unable to create the tab. The style's aren't in use so I am unsure as to why it won't work. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot to explain why a tab style is not selectable for more clarity?

Comment: @Swetha, I've just added a screenshot and edit - not sure if that clarifies it anymore for you... I'm also extremely perplexed by what is happening!